# Installation of Serato DJ in WINE failed

Tags: software-installation, wine

I just started using Linux with the latest version of Ubuntu.

I want to run the latest version of Serato DJ on Ubuntu.

I installed the latest version of WINE.

I download the latest installer for Serato DJ (file extension .exe) and the launched it with WINE.

I then accept the EULA and the install started. I then get the a message saying "Setup Failed" with "0x80070643 - Installation Failure".

There's an error log that I posted at [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3xg7u2vncyqg3z0/Error%20log.txt?dl=0).

I tried going back in versions (before 1.9.2) but the only version that works is 1.0.0.

The first error message in the log is "Error 0x80070643: Failed to install MSI package."

I'm new to all this so please start from the basics.

thank you!

Comment: the only "Serato" application listed in Wine HQ is [Serato Scratch Live](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=10225),so most probably your program will not work with Wine.

Comment: @dadexix86 Thank you, I had noticed that but I was hopping that there would be a way to use Serato DJ. Since Serato Scratch Live is more basic.

Comment: Never mind that Wine HQ didn't mention the app, it means nothing except that nobody reported the app. Try latest Wine, and if it won't work, [report a bug](https://wiki.winehq.org/Bugs).

Comment: @Hi-Angel when you say try latest Wine do you mean that I should update my WINE to the latest version?

Comment: @SUPERETDUPER I mean to update to the latest development version; also it is part of what's written on the page about what to do before bugreporting. Wine has [a PPA with development snapshots](https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu), you can install from there.

Comment: @Hi-Angel Thanks a lot, I submitted a [bug report](https://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=41095)

Comment: @SUPERETDUPER ah, btw: did installation work with `1.0.0` version? It's an important information, which would be nice to mention in bugreport; you can also add then `Regression` keyword to the title: regressions usually take more attention, and are easier to fix.

Comment: @Hi-Angel What does Regression mean

Comment: It's when something worked, but a update broke it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The system requirements for Serato DJ requires Windows 7.

Using the command `winecfg` I changed my windows from XP to Windows 7.

I no longer get the installation failure.

Comment: Note that these days it needs to be at least `Windows 8` to work.

Answer (score 0):

Got similar error today. Answer from [@staad](https://askubuntu.com/a/809293/231159) is correct, but these days it needs to be at least Windows 8.

1. run `winecfg`
2. on `Applications` tab set for `Default Settings` the value of `Windows Version` to at least `Windows 8`.